# How to create a range to search for in a text file using two strings inside the text file and search in between those two strings?

Tags: python

Currently this is what i have, once i found the word fail , it needs to search above the fail string and display up until it hits another string i set. and then inquire user for the string to search within that area. Am i correct in creating a new text file to store the lines that contains the string from user ?

```
from typing import Any
from collections import Counter

errorList = []

with open('File1.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    if line.__contains__('Fail '):
        errorList.append(line)


errorList = [i[30:56] for i in errorList]
print("Failed are = ", errorList)

string = input("What string do you like to search for in this test case? ")

f = open('File1.txt')
f1 = open('StringSearch.txt', 'a')

for line in f.readlines():
    if string in line:
        f1.write(line)
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you want the code to do. Please show an example of what the input file might contain, and exactly what the output should be as a result.

Comment: This might be a candidate for regular expressions. Please add example data from `File1.txt` that shows the fail lines, user string, and the start string that you set.

Comment: this is an example for the File1.text:
-initializing 
- entering system
- error1, code error, error2
-Parse error
-Failed
-system exiting
-system complete

The program is supposed to look for the 'Fail' string first and then set a range from the 'testcase entering' string up to 'Fail' string. Supposed the user inputs error as the string he likes to search in that range , it will output the lines that contain the string error within the range only


Sample output:

Comment: Sample output:
Failed test found: <line with fail string>
what string do you like to search in this test case ? 
- <lines w/ string>